# JSP pagerDeluxe not working

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have a footer in a `dataTableEx`, used to turn pages inside the table when the list displayed has more than 10 elements. 
The list comes from a `Stateful` Java Bean, where Javascript elements are present and are correctly working.

The footer:

```
<f:facet name="footer">
<hx:panelBox styleClass="panelBox" id="box1" >
<hx:pagerGoto styleClass="pagerGoto" id="goto1" />
<hx:pagerDeluxe styleClass="pagerDeluxe" id="deluxe1"/>                         
</hx:panelBox>
```

But the arrows `nextPage`, `previousPage`, `firstPage`, `lastPage` associated with the element `pagerDeluxe` do not work.

Notice that `pagerGoto` is working. I also tried with `pagerSimple` and `pagerWeb` and they do work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Fran